# How to make Dstat show units

Tags: centos, monitoring

Im using Dstat on Centos to monitor incoming network, and it only shows numbers, not the B/Mb that I have seen on other peoples Dstats, how do I make it show the units?
Example of current Dstat:

```
[root@vps ~]# dstat -n --socket --integer
-net/total- ------sockets------
 recv  send|tot tcp udp raw frg
   0     0 |192  23   2   0 117
  18M  592k|192  23   2   0 136
  18M  598k|192  23   2   0 116
  19M  601k|192  23   2   0 132
  19M  596k|192  23   2   0 141
  20M  599k|192  23   2   0 117
  20M  594k|192  23   2   0 118
```

Is it not suposed to show units in the sockets row?

Answer (score 1):

That's because the 'sockets' stats are counters, not units. They're counting the sockets, not network traffic. Units would likely be metric, so if you get over 1024 you might see a 1K in there.

Comment: How do you get the statistics for incoming bandwidth?